# How to trigger the proper JTable event based on user input and how to calculate totals?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a JTable and I have an xml file with stock symbols and their names.
I want the user to enter the stock symbol in the first column and when he press Enter to see the name of the Stock in the second column.
What is the proper JTable event to use?
Also, is it possible to calculate totals from cells with numeric values?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean calculate totals from cells? Some initial code would help.

Comment: For example in a row with number of stocks and their value, a column with the name total could calculate their multiplication.

Comment: You can use the `TableModel` to access and modify data among the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `TableChanged` method of `TableModelListener` to access the data entered and then make the calculations you need.

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
    Object data = model.getValueAt(e.getRow(), e.getColumn());

    //do something
}
```

Comment: One little correction here, e.getRow() must be replaced with e.getFirstRow()